# Is is possible to emit value on every observable completion that will go to the subscribers using single pipe?

Tags: rxjs

I need to invoke multiple web request in declared order. Every consecutive request depends on the outcome of previous one. I would like to emit event after each request is completed that will go to the subscriber.

Right now I am "tapping" value of each request and emitting result using separate `Subject`. Is it possible to do this using single pipe with operators?

Here is code example

```
fromEvent(pauseButton, "click")
  .pipe(
    tap(()=>{
      subscribedLabel.innerHTML="";
      tapedLabel.innerHTML="";
    }),
    tap(v => (tapedLabel.innerHTML = "started")),
    concatMapTo(of("phase 1 completed").pipe(delay(1000))),
    tap(v => (tapedLabel.innerHTML = v)),
    concatMapTo(of("phase 2 completed").pipe(delay(1000))),
    tap(v => (tapedLabel.innerHTML = v))
    )
  .subscribe(v => {
    console.log(v);
    subscribedLabel.innerHTML = v;
  });
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-6jza7h?file=index.ts

The expected outcome is that `subscribedLabel.innerHTML` will change the same way as `tapedLabel.innerHTML`

Comment: @DV please explain how to improve the question - its clear and complete IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It not clear what you're after, but this is a way you can use 4 consecutive calls and accumulate all their responses into one object.

```
function fakeHTTP(resW): Observable<string> {
  return of(resW).pipe(delay(1000))
}

fromEvent(button, "click").pipe(
  concatMap(_ => 
    fakeHTTP(1).pipe(
      map(res => ({first: res}))
    )
  ),
  tap(_ => console.log("First Request Complete")),
  concatMap(first => 
    fakeHTTP(2).pipe(
      map(res => ({...first, second: res}))
    )
  ),
  tap(_ => console.log("Second Request Complete")),
  concatMap(second => 
    fakeHTTP(3).pipe(
      map(res => ({...second, third: res}))
    )
  ),
  tap(_ => console.log("Third Request Complete")),
  concatMap(third => 
    fakeHTTP(4).pipe(
      map(res => ({...third, fourth: res}))
    )
  ),
  tap(_ => console.log("Fourth Request Complete"))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

The output of this is as follows:

```
// Wait 1s
First Request Complete
// Wait 1s
Second Request Complete
// Wait 1s
Third Request Complete
// Wait 1s
Fourth Request Complete
{"first":1,"second":2,"third":3,"fourth":4} // <- Value sent to subscribe
```

#### Update #1: Pass Values Up the Call Chain

You can pass values up the call chain, but it gets a bit more complicated. You want each step only to work on values from the previous step, but to ignore (emit unaltered) the values from further up the chain.

One way you can do this is to tag each response. I do this with a `pass` flag that can be true or false. The final operation is to remove the flag.

Here is what that looks like:

```
function fakeHTTP(resW): Observable<string> {
  return of(resW).pipe(delay(1000))
}

fromEvent(button, "click").pipe(
  concatMap(_ => 
    fakeHTTP(1)
  ),
  tap(_ => console.log("First Request Complete")),
  concatMap(first => 
    fakeHTTP(2).pipe(
      map(res => ({pass: false, payload: res})),
      startWith({pass: true, payload: first})
    )
  ),
  tap(({pass}) => {
    if(!pass) console.log("Second Request Complete")
  }),
  concatMap(second => second.pass ? 
    of(second) :
    fakeHTTP(3).pipe(
      map(res => ({pass: false, payload: res})),
      startWith({...second, pass: true})
    )
  ),
  tap(({pass}) => {
    if(!pass) console.log("Third Request Complete")
  }),
  concatMap(third => third.pass ?
    of(third) :
    fakeHTTP(4).pipe(
      map(res => ({pass: false, payload: res})),
      startWith({...third, pass: true})
    )
  ),
  tap(({pass}) => {
    if(!pass) console.log("Second Request Complete")
  }),
  map(({payload}) => payload)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

The output of this is as follows:

```
// Wait 1s
First Request Complete // <- console log from tap
1 // <- console log from subscribe
// Wait 1s
Second Request Complete // <- console log from tap
2 // <- console log from subscribe
// Wait 1s
Third Request Complete // <- console log from tap
3 // <- console log from subscribe
// Wait 1s
Second Request Complete // <- console log from tap
4 // <- console log from subscribe
```

#### Update #2: When recursion is possible

You can also make recursive calls where each new call depends on the previous call and some base-case ends the recursion. RxJS jas `expand` as a built-in way to recurse.

In this example, each new call to `fakeHTTP` uses the value emitted by the previous call directly.

```
function fakeHTTP(resW): Observable<string> {
  return of(resW).pipe(delay(1000))
}

fromEvent(button, "click").pipe(
  map(_ => 1),
  expand(proj => proj < 4 ?
    fakeHTTP(++proj) :
    EMPTY
  )
).subscribe(console.log);
```

The output of this is as follows:

```
// Wait 1s
1
// Wait 1s
2
// Wait 1s
3
// Wait 1s
4
```

#### Update #3: Separate observables

```
function fakeHTTP(resW): Observable<string> {
  return of(resW).pipe(delay(1000))
}

const first$ = fromEvent(button, "click").pipe(
  concatMap(_ => fakeHTTP(1)),
  share()
);
const second$ = first$.pipe(
  concatMap(first => fakeHTTP(2)),
  share()
);
const third$ = second$.pipe(
  concatMap(second => fakeHTTP(3)),
  share()
);
const fourth$ = third$.pipe(
  concatMap(third => fakeHTTP(4))
);

merge(
  first$, 
  second$, 
  third$, 
  fourth$
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Here's another, more annoying way to write *almost* the exact same thing.

```
function fakeHTTP(resW): Observable<string> {
  return of(resW).pipe(delay(1000))
}

fromEvent(button, "click").pipe(
  map(_ => fakeHTTP(1).pipe(
    share(),
  )),
  map(first$ => ([first$.pipe(
    concatMap(firstR => fakeHTTP(2)),
    share()
  ), first$])),
  map(([second$, ...tail]) => ([second$.pipe(
    concatMap(secondR => fakeHTTP(3)),
    share()
  ),second$, ...tail])),
  map(([third$, ...tail]) => ([third$.pipe(
    concatMap(thirdR => fakeHTTP(4))
  ),third$, ...tail])),
  concatMap(calls => merge(...calls))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: I want result of each call to be emited to the subscriber just when it is done. Its kind of like progress indicator. Waiting for all requests is very different from what I desire. So for N requests I want N emisions - but not after all requests is done but right after each request

Comment: Thanks for the great effort. It seems that using pure rx to do what I want is more complex than the problem itself. Therfore, I am ending up using separate `Subject` that is returned to the caller and then emiting values to it by "tapping" each response - as it seams to be the simplest solution.

Comment: I've added in a third possibility that just uses separate observables for fo each call. You may be right that a separate subject is a cleaner solution? Using a `subject` or using `share` are both solutions that multicast your observables. At scale, that's a performance hit, but realistically it's too minor to matter